# Ambigous use of `continue` after upgrading from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

I have a `swift` project and I'm using there Amazon Web Services.

I have a function responsible for uploading image to my `S3` bucket, in Swift 2.2 it worked well and the code was as follows:

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:CognitoRegionType,
                                                            identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:CognitoRegionType, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration



let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest.body = NSURL(string: "file://"+pathToFile)
uploadRequest.key = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString + "." + ext
uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
uploadRequest.contentType = contentType + ext

let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in

        if (task.completed) {
        ...
```

Now, after upgrading to Swift 3, I have:

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:CognitoRegionType,
                                                            identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:CognitoRegionType, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration



let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest?.body = URL(string: "file://"+pathToFile)
uploadRequest?.key = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString + "." + ext
uploadRequest?.bucket = S3BucketName
uploadRequest?.contentType = contentType + ext

let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
    transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in

        if (task.isCompleted) {
```

Now in the last statement `transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock` throws an error that says

```
'continueWithBlock' has been renamed to 'continue(_:)'
```

so I follow their advices and change it to:

```
transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continue {
```

but then it throws me an error:

```
Ambigous use of continue
```

Available methods are here:

[image]

but I'm not sure which one could I use in this case. Can you help me with that?

Comment: `continueWithBlock()` -> `continue(block:)`. In Swift 3 `xWithY()` becomes `x(y:)`.

Comment: I tried replacing it as you suggested, but then the error says `AWSTask<AnyObject> has no member continue(block:)`...

Comment: Did you converted code to Swift 3 yourself, or it's official code from AWS lib developers? If it's not your conversion, you should contact lib developers with this problem, if convers is yours, you still should check AWS lib source for updated to Swift 3 version. Because it looks like bad case of name conversion.

Comment: @user28434 I am using (hopefully) the latest version of that library, as discussed here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/413 I'm using `2.4.9` version and it is already converted to swift 3 (at least I hope, during opening my whole project in xcode it asked me to convert everything to swift 3, I hit apply and got this error as a result)

Comment: `transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).\`continue\` { ... }` could be a solution as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the issue, it was easier than I thought... It was mentioned here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/473 and said to change the

```
transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continue { ... }
```

to

```
transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continue ({ ... })
```

Method naming in this case is indeed annoying, but it works.